# How to correct the height when using position:relative and negative top

Tags: html, css, position

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="page.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="body"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color: cyan;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

#body{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Rendered page looks like this:

[image]

The relatively positioned div#body is taken out of the normal flow, and we can see the cyan body at the bottom. Is it possible to fix it, so the body height ended where div#body ends?

I can't use margin-top: -100px, because on the real page it breaks the horizontal centering in Opera.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xfqzqhws/

Comment: Why don't you just make the header 100px less in height, and not move the div#body 100px up?

Comment: Would making the body position absolute not work for you?

Comment: @rblarsen Because on the real page the header has a background image, and body has another bg image, that must overlap the header

Comment: Or you could apply the margin-botom: -100px to the other two divs?

Comment: @Aaron margin-bottom: -100px for the header also breaks the centering in Opera. I tried it,.

Comment: what if you add padding-top: 100px; and margin-top: -100px; to the #body?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if this will work for you

```
#body{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:-100px;

}
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, without top absolute positioning doesn't work

Comment: Any specific browser? I checked this on FF and chrome http://jsfiddle.net/xfqzqhws/5/

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I solved the problem by using the absolute positioning